# php_mysql problem image display from database

Tags: php, mysql, image-processing

I am trying to display an image from my database using PHP & MySQL. I have searched in the internet how to do that and I tied it with code I found but the only thing that is appeared in the screen is a file broken or something like that.

My code is:

```
<?php    
if( ( isset($_POST['submitdisplay'] ) )&&( $_POST['pwdADMIN']=="admin1986"))
{
    $findm = mysql_query("SELECT idmeasure, vmanufacturer, vmodel, vtype, volume, yearofvehicle, motion, timereact,time_0_18m, 
    time_0_100m, time_0_200m, time_0_300m, time_0_400m, speedexit, time_0_100km, typeoftyre, dmeasure, temperature, sceneryofmeasure, 
    horsepower, vehicleforce, drivername, email, emailappearornot, sitelink, stock, weightofvehicle, videoofvehicle, comments, password  
    FROM measurementofvehicle WHERE approved='NO'");

    echo '<table border="2" style="width: 100%; align: center;" bordercolor="red">';
    $tmpid="";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($findm, MYSQL_NUM))
    {
        echo '<tr>';                   
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[0];echo '</font></td>'; 
        $tmpid=$row[0];
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[1];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[2];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[3];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[4];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[5];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[6];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[7];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[8];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[9];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[10];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[11];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[12];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[13];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[14];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[15];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[16];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[17];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[18];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[19];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[20];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[21];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[22];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[23];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[24];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[25];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[26];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[27];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[28];echo '</font></td>'; 
        echo '<td align="center"><font color="red">';echo $row[29];echo '</font></td>';  

        $idr = "";

        $getidr = "SELECT fidRtime FROM measurementofvehicle_receiptoftime_receiptofforce_imageofvehicle WHERE fidmeasure='$tmpid'";

        $r1 = mysql_query($getidr)or die(mysql_error());
        while($srow = mysql_fetch_array($r1) )
        { 
            $idr=$srow['fidRtime'];
        }    
        echo "$idr";
        echo "<img src=\"GetImage.php?id=$idsr\">\n";
        echo '</tr>';       
   }        
   echo '</table>';                
}
?>
```

I retrieve the id of the image from another table,

```
$Receiptoftime = "CREATE TABLE Receiptoftime( 
        idRtime INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        nameRtime VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        typeRtime VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        sizeRtime INT NOT NULL,
        contentRtime MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(idRtime)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci";
```

`idRtime` is the id I need to retrieve the id from the table that it's stores the image.

That table is

```
$Receiptoftime = "CREATE TABLE Receiptoftime(
        idRtime INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        nameRtime VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        typeRtime VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        sizeRtime INT NOT NULL,
        contentRtime MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(idRtime)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci";
```

The code I found I see that I had to write a script that generates the image and then use the tag image so that I can't get the image. The script that generates that image is,

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    $connect=mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("dragtimesgr") or die(mysql_error());

    $id=addlashes($_REQUEST['id']);

    $image=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM receiptoftime WHERE idRtime='$id'")or die(mysql_error());
    $image=mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
    $image=$image['contentRtime'];

    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

    echo $image;
?>
```

Can you help me? The only thing that appears in the screen is an icon, that seems to be broken. I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Ok. you ask how to display an image retrieved from a database, then include about 200 billion lines of utterly irrelevant code before showing the 10 or so lines that actuall do the retrieving/displaying. NO one here is going to read all that garbage. Simplify your question.

Comment: I second Marc's request - "simplify your question." It's OK to tell us you've tried different solutions but you don't necessarily have to show us. If you're looking for ways to display binary stored in a database,  ask for examples. Fixing code and helping you help yourself are two very different things.

Comment: i just want to display images from the database ........ the code or the posts i have found in the internet didn't help me at all ........ i don't know even if my code is correct ....... an example how to handle this would help ....... the upload of the image as a code was a piece of cake ....... but displaying it was a big problem for me since its the first time i tring to programa with mysql and php ..........

Comment: @Marc B: Whilst I sympathise with the point made - you could have phrased that far more kindly, considering it was a first time poster.

Comment: how much time would be spent if people have to explain to every first timer how to ask a question.  there is a faq for a reason. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @dogmatic69: A worthwhile endeavour perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you call the image script directly from your browser, e.g. by typing `http://host/path/GetImage.php?id=1` or whatever into the browser's location bar?

(Also, you need to fix that script so it isn't such a big injection attack target!)

Comment: Additionally if `http://host/path/GetImage.php?id=1` don't display any error messages you can check if the data are the same as the image that you upload — maybe it's truncated to the size of database field.